# _Layout.cshtml css broken in ASP.NET Core Web Application

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core Web Application, and I am having some css issues. The standard _Layout.cshtml file that is created when the project is created has barely been touched, aside from a view name changes and a couple of pages have been added. Here, you can see the full _Layout.cshtml file:

```
@inject Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.JavaScriptSnippet JavaScriptSnippet
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="html">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Biggest Loser</title>

    <environment names="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>
    @Html.Raw(JavaScriptSnippet.FullScript)
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">Biggest Loser</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Weights" asp-action="Index">Weights</a></li>
                        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="UserDetails" asp-action="Index">Target Weight</a></li>
                        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Weights" asp-action="Summary">Summary</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    @await Html.PartialAsync("_LoginPartial")
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container body-content">
            @RenderBody()
            <hr/>
            <footer>
                <a href="http://www.needlecast.co.uk"><p>&copy; 2017 <img src="~/img/Asset 6.png" id="footerphoto" /></p></a>
            </footer>
        </div>

        <environment names="Development">
            <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
            <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        </environment>
        <environment names="Staging,Production">
            <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                    crossorigin="anonymous"
                    integrity="sha384-K+ctZQ+LL8q6tP7I94W+qzQsfRV2a+AfHIi9k8z8l9ggpc8X+Ytst4yBo/hH+8Fk">
            </script>
            <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                    crossorigin="anonymous"
                    integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
            </script>
            <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        </environment>
        @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, it is almost identical to the original _Layout.cshtml (bar the aforementioned changes) that is created on project creation.

I have almost finished the project, however, I have hit quite a roadblock. Whenever I debug the project, this is what I am greeted with:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dd5m.png

This is very different to what should be seen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xpk6M.png

Ignore the carousel and text, it is just the navbar that has disappeared as well as the formatting of the text on the Home/Index.cshtml view. The formatting was all working before I published it to Azure. The weird thing is, I have the project on source control and the previous versions (which worked before this, btw) now have the same problem. I have reset VS 2017 settings, all the code in the _Layout.cshtml has been reset and I have reset to the defualt CSS in the wwwroot folder. I have had someone with 30+ years on the issue but to no avail. Because of this, I have come to the internet to help me. If there are any other files or settings you need to see/know about, please comment and i will be happy to show you.

Comment: Did you reverse those image references?

Comment: no, i just wanted to show what the navbar should look like, as supposed to what it does look like.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a general fix my code site.  It's for asking specific code related questions and getting specific code related answers.  It's unclear what your question is other than please help me fix my code.  You should strongly consider rewording your question so that it asks a specific question.

Comment: There's too many variables here, but generally speaking it looks like something that should be being loaded in, isn't. Check the developer console for 404s. Verify that your bundling/minimization is working correctly.

Comment: The thing is, I dont know what is causing the issue, and so i cannot narrow down the question. If i knew at all what the problem was i would, but i dont, so i cant

Comment: It will help if you upload the project to a live server so that we can look at it for you. Without being able to see the code makes it really hard to find the issue.

Comment: This part is the oddest "I have the project on source control and the previous versions (which worked before this, btw) now have the same problem."  Typically going to an old version that worked and then re-laying in the functionality/html to see when it breaks is a good way to narrow it down.  But it's odd that an old version that once worked now doesn't.  If that's really true it'd seems like it must be an environment issue but I'd re-double check that the old working versions no longer work before I spent too much time investigating the environment.

Comment: I just copied your layout into a fresh core project & it worked OK for me (http://imgur.com/a/c7Sny).. My guess is that it is a css issue but would need to see a live site to troubleshoot it more.

Comment: Perhaps check your `_ViewStart.cshtml` file - it should simply have the following: `@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have actually fixed the problem. It turns out after I had tried to install a bootstrap theme, it didn't remove all the files necessary when I tried to delete it. Thanks, for all of your help, this question can now be closed.